# Finding the eigenvalues - missing a trick?

Tags: linear-algebra

I can compute the eigenvalues of the product of these matrices $X_1 X_2$ by multiplying out the matrices, but I'm certain I am missing a trick that will make this computation less tedious. Any hints?

$X_1$:
$$
    \begin{matrix}     
    1 & 2 \\
    0 & 2 \\
    1 & 0 \\
    2 & 0 \\
    \end{matrix}
$$

$X_2$:

$$
    \begin{matrix}     
    0 & 2 & 3 & 1\\
    2 & 1 & 3 & -1 \\
    \end{matrix}
$$

The product of these matrices being:

\begin{matrix}     
    4 & 6 & 8 & -1\\
    4 & 6 & 12 & 0 \\
    0 & 2 & 3 & 1  \\
    0 & 4 & 6 & 2 \\
    \end{matrix}

$$
$$

Comment: "I'm certain I am missing a trick that will make this computation less tedious" Why?

Comment: Mainly because this was a question on a previous exam - I doubt the instructor would expect us to find the eigenvalues for a 4x4 matrix.

Comment: What would a rank of the resulting matrix be?

Comment: The first two rows of the product matrix are incorrect. I'm not sure if this helps at all with the question though.

Comment: The only thing special I can see is that row 4 is twice row 3, so the matrix is not invertible, making $\lambda = 0$ one of the eigenvalues. Also, if you calculate $\det(A-\lambda I) = 0$, using the zeros in the first column to your advantage should make the determinant a lot less tedious.

Comment: @Matthias: The matrix has rank at most $2$ (being a product of matrices of rank at most $2$). So at least two of its eigenvalues are zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The non-zero eigenvalues of $X_1 X_2$ are the same as the non-zero eigenvalues of $X_2 X_1$.